# jQuery - filtering elements by id

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select a group of elements with a similar class. and then filter the selection by the element id. Is there a better way to go about this?

Then using that same id, I want to do something to a element set up with the same show entitcal class

```
$('ElementClass-1').attr('ElementId-1');
   $(this).hover(function(){
        ..do stuff
       });
  });

<a class="ElementClass-1" id="ElementId-1">hover me</a>
<a class="ElementClass-1" id="ElementId-2">hover me</a>
<a class="ElementClass-1" id="ElementId-3">hover me</a>
<div style="display:none; class="ElementId-1">show me</div>
<div style="display:none; class="ElementId-2">show me</div>
<div style="display:none; class="ElementId-3">show me</div>
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete, so any way would be better. Why not use the ID selector: `$('#ElementId').something()`?

Comment: You can only have one of the same ID per page, so just select it directly by the Id as Felix mentions above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below,

```
$(ElementClass).each(function () {
    $('.' + this.id).<your_function>();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery's multiple attribute selector
http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/

the first attribute is going to be "class" and the second attribute is going to be "id"

Comment: Why not use class and id selectors?

Comment: Since IDs are supposed to be unique, you'd only need the ID selector anyway. But of course you *could* combine the selectors in any possible way, e.g. `#id.class`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a class with the same name for all the elements just for selecting? something like

```
class="ElementSelector"
```

later you can use that class for the selection